# PHP preg_match not showing brackets and its content in result string

Tags: php, html

Something simple

```
$stringData = file_get_contents('testtext.txt');    
$regular='/beginning "(.*?)"end/ueU';
preg_match($regular, $stringData,$match);
echo $match[0];
```

just to get the string between the strings beginning" and the string "end

the result is something like:

Member groups activity RSS title - "[Site Name] | [User Display#. Name] | Groups Activity

but the text is (and I would like to get everything):

```
</strong> and <strong>member groups activity RSS title - "[Site Name] | [User Display]
<EMAIL@ADDRESS> #. Name] | Groups Activity
```

it doesn't show the brackets and the text in the brackets<> in the result string.

Answer (score 2):

That's how HTML is rendered in a browser:

```
echo htmlentities($match[0]);
```